# How to programmatically change/update data in Python PyQt4 TableView?

Tags: python, pyqt4, tableview, qwidget

I would like to have a table within a `QWidget` window and update the table each time the user enters a value in the `lineEdit` field. How do I do this programmatically?

status: I am getting the following error to your code:

> TypeError: QAbstractTableModel.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex, int, int):
>   argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui , QtCore
import sys

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s


class ABCTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self,data,parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self,parent)
        self.__data=data     # Initial Data

    def rowCount( self, parent ):
        return len(self.__data)

    def columnCount( self , parent ):
        return len(self.__data)

    def data ( self , index , role ):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            value = self.__data[row][column]
            return QtCore.QString(str(value))

    def setData(self, index, value):
        self.__data[index.row()][index.column()] = value
        return True

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable      

    def insertRows(self , position , rows , item , parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        # beginInsertRows (self, QModelIndex parent, int first, int last)
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(),position,position)
        self.__data.append(item) # Item must be an array
        self.endInsertRows()
        return True

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow , QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,None)
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,None)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableModel=ABCTableModel([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]])
        self.tableView.setModel(self.tableModel) 
        self.lineEdit_1 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableModel.insertRows(self.lineEdit_1.text(),self.lineEdit_2.text(), self.lineEdit_3.text())

if  __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow() # <-- Instantiate QMainWindow object.
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement [Model View Programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) for this. Python Model View Programming is fairly simple.

Attach a Model to your TableView , and take the input in your LineEdit and insert it into the model, and rest of the work will be taken care of.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui , QtCore
import sys
class ABCTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self,data,parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self,parent)
        self.__data=data     # Initial Data

    def rowCount( self, parent ):
        return len(self.__data)

    def columnCount( self , parent ):
        return len(self.__data[])

    def data ( self , index , role ):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            value = self.__data[row][column]
            return QtCore.QString(str(value))

    def setData(self, index, value):
        self.__data[index.row()][index.column()] = value
        return True

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable      

    def insertRows(self , position , rows , item , parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        # beginInsertRows (self, QModelIndex parent, int first, int last)
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(),len(self.__data),len(self.__data)+1)
        self.__data.append(item) # Item must be an array
        self.endInsertRows()
        return True

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow , QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,None)
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,None)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableModel=ABCTableModel([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]])
        self.tableView.setModel(self.tableModel) 
        self.lineEdit_1 = QtGui.QlineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QlineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtGui.QlineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableModel.insertRows(self.lineEdit_1.text(),self.lineEdit_2.text(), self.lineEdit_3.text())

if  __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow() # <-- Instantiate QMainWindow object.
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got a few errors and was able to update accordingly. However I am still getting the following error: TypeError: QAbstractTableModel.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex, int, int): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'. Here is the updated code: from PyQt4 import QtGui , QtCore
import sys

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

Comment: class ABCTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self,data,parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self,parent)
        self.__data=data     # Initial Data

    def rowCount( self, parent ):
        return len(self.__data)

    def columnCount( self , parent ):
        return len(self.__data)

    def data ( self , index , role ):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            value = self.__data[row][column]
            return QtCore.QString(str(value))

Comment: @CM : I have updated the code, take a look. To understand what i did take a look :http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows